# Multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am writing a Python script **(`in Python 2.7`)** wherein I need to generate around 500,000 uniform random numbers within a range. I need to do this 4 times, perform some calculations on them and write out the 4 files.

At the moment I am doing: `(this is just part of my for loop, not the entire code)`

```
random_RA = []
for i in xrange(500000):
    random_RA.append(np.random.uniform(6.061,6.505)) # FINAL RANDOM RA 

random_dec = []
for i in xrange(500000):
    random_dec.append(np.random.uniform(min(data_dec_1),max(data_dec_1))) # FINAL RANDOM 'dec'
```

to generate the random numbers within the range. I am running **`Ubuntu 14.04`** and when I run the program I also open my system manager to see how the 8 CPU's I have are working. I seem to notice that when the program is running, only 1 of the 8 CPU's seem to work at 100% efficiency. So the entire program takes me around 45 minutes to complete.

I noticed that it is possible to use all the CPU's to my advantage using the module `Multiprocessing`

**I would like to know if this is enough in my example:**

```
random_RA = []
for i in xrange(500000): 
    multiprocessing.Process()
    random_RA.append(np.random.uniform(6.061,6.505)) # FINAL RANDOM RA
```

i.e adding just the line `multiprocessing.Process()`, would that be enough?

Comment: Have you even read the documentation? https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I did read it and I think the above might work. But before trying I would like to know if it will from an exper

Comment: Answering your question: that definitely would **not** be enough.

Comment: @freakish How should I proceed?

Comment: No, it is not enough and that call is incomplete. Even if it were complete, you're putting the processing in the wrong loop, so if you had called it correctly there, you'd spin up 500000 threads, instead of the 4 you want.

Comment: @Srivatsan Start by reading docs. You need to pass a function to `Process()` constructor. But there's waaaaaay too many details to explain. Read docs provided by Aleksander.

Comment: @freakish Ok I shall do so

Comment: @Srivatsan Note that generating the random numbers should be a fairly inexpensive operation, especially if the whole program is taking 45 minutes. It's probably more important to parallelize the calculations you're doing on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use multiprocessing, you should avoid shared state (like your `random_RA` list) as much as possible.
Instead, try to use a `Pool` and its `map` method:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def generate_random_ra(x):
    return np.random.uniform(6.061, 6.505)

def generate_random_dec(x):
    return np.random.uniform(min(data_dec_1), max(data_dec_1))

pool = Pool(cpu_count())
random_RA = pool.map(generate_random_ra, xrange(500000))
random_dec = pool.map(generate_random_dec, xrange(500000))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
import multiprocessing
import random

def worker(i):
    random.uniform(1,100000)
    print i,'done'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(4):
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args=(i,))
        t.start()
    print 'All the processes have been started.'
```

You must gate the `t = multiprocess.Process(...)` with `__name__ == "__main__"` as each worker calls this program (module) again to find out what it has to do. If the gating didn't happen it would spawn more processes ...

Just for completeness, generating 500000 random numbers is not going to take you 45 minutes so i assume there are some intensive calculations going on here: you may want to look at them closely.